Node-Gyp keeps giving error exit code 1 when trying to use with Electron and robotjs on a Mac
I've literally tried everything to get robotjs to work with Electron JS. I've reinstalled Xcode, set up Python 3, changed node versions and rebuilt gyp to no avail. I'm trying to capture mouse events outside the Electron app. I've also tried iohook and creating my own C++ addon as ChatGPT suggested. A little bit of help would definitely be appreciated. These are the errors I'm getting:
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/***/.nvm/versions/node/v23.2.0/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:216:23)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 20.3.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/***/.nvm/versions/node/v23.2.0/bin/node" "/Users/***/.nvm/versions/node/v23.2.0/bin/node-gyp" "build"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/***/Apps/***-***-desktop/
gyp ERR! node -v v23.2.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.2.0
gyp ERR! not ok ```

